# How to extract all possible sub-products which match specific pattern?

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering

I have an expression of the form

```
expr = 3*(a.b)*(c.d)*f[x] + 5*(m.n)*(p.q)*(r.s)*f[y]
```

and want to extract all possible subexpressions matching the pattern `((_).(_))*f[_]`.
Expected result (in arbitrary order) is:

```
{(a.b)*f[x], (c.d)*f[x], (m.n)*f[y], (p.q)*f[y], (r.s)*f[y]}
```

Built-in function `Cases` seem to ignore `Flat` Attribute of `Times` and gives nothing:

```
Cases[expr, ((_).(_))*f[_], Infinity]
```

> {}

How can I get all possible subexpressions matching the pattern `((_).(_))*f[_]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get all the different ways this pattern can match, we can use `ReplaceList`, since none of `Cases`, `Replace`, `ReplaceAll` tries to match the same part more than once. Here is one way:

```
ReplaceList[expr, 
 d_. + Times[c___, Dot[a_, b_], f[x_]] :> Dot[a, b] f[x]]
```

> {a.b f[x], c.d f[x], m.n f[y], p.q f[y], r.s f[y]}

The reason I'm writing `Dot[a_, b_]` and not just `a_.b_` is that looking at the `FullForm` of what I'm trying to match always seems to help me figure out a good pattern to use :)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html) with the option `Overlaps -> All`:

```
SequenceCases[List @@ expr, { _.  a_Dot  b_f} :> a b, Overlaps -> All]
```

> ```
>  {c.d f[x], a.b f[x], r.s f[y], p.q f[y], m.n f[y]}
> ```